# Can anyone tell me how to fix this error.?

Tags: angular, settings

PS C:\Users\Public\angular> ng new "my-new-angular-app"                                                                                                                         ng : File C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

```
                                              .
```

Comment: Please checkout [how do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you faced that error when using vscode terminal. Run your command from command prompt can solve this error. [image]

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. But next time , please format your questions.It was hard to understand without format.